# C# List intersect with certain item from tuple returned as tuple

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists.

```
1) List<StringA>
2) List<Tuple<StringB, StringC>>
```

I want to match the lists on StringA and StringC and return the result as `List<Tuple<StringB, StringC>>`.

How do i select the StringC in the tuple with an Intersect? I tried:

```
List1.Intersect(List2.Select(c => c.Item2));
```

But that does not return it as a Tuple.

How can i solve this?

Comment: .NET only defines `Tuples` up to eight members. What should happen if there are more members in the intereection? (Are you sure "tuple" here means a specific type or the general CS concept of an ordered collection?)

Comment: @Richard he's not trying to create a new type by any means, really he's just filtering his second list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
var query = List2.Where(t => List1.Contains(t.Item2));
```

You can also utilize a `HashSet` for performance purpose like:

```
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(List1);
var query = List2.Where(t => hashSet.Contains(t.Item2));
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
List2.Where(c => List1.Contains(c.Item2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
            List<string> one = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
            List<Tuple<string, string>> two = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            two.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Jack", "x"));
            two.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ben", "b"));
            two.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Kyle", "c"));

            var result = two.Where(x => one.Contains(x.Item2));
```

result = ("Ben", "b") and ("Kyle", "c")